# Exported APK from eclipse is Invalid

Tags: android, eclipse, export, apk, signed

I am exporting APK from eclipse. It is exporting successfully but the size of exported signed apk is just 1.9 MB whereas the size of unsigned APK is around 13 MB. Unsigned APK is working well but when I exported a signed APK and tried to install it. It shows me an alert of Invalid APK file or Can't Parse the Package.

I have checked for conflicting libraries. 
Also have tried exporting APK disabling the build automatically feature of eclipse.
Increased the heap size in eclipse.ini

and have tried many more troubleshooting techniques but all in vein. Please help.

Comment: do you get any exception during exporting the apk ?

Comment: no there is no exception.

Comment: Try disable the "build automatically" before exporting your apk

Comment: disable Build automatically and clean your project then export it

Comment: No success; Still signed apk size is half of unsigned apk

Comment: and while installing I am facing the same error

Comment: @AashutoshPrashar  are u using progaurd?

Comment: no... but might be libraries have proguard... I am using social libraries of Facebook SDK, Twiiter Fabric and Google Play Services

Comment: Yes, Twitter fabric included a proguard in my project. I have commented the code and now I am getting Conversion to Dalvik Format Failed with error code 1.